# Why would the dir command list a directory as empty when it is not?

Tags: powershell, directory, jupyter-notebook

so I was using Ipython Notebook (now known as Jupyter Notebook) and noticed that when I went to the Documents directory from home, there were no files or subdirectories. At first, I thought that this may be due to rendering problems with ipynb but when I went into PowerShell, I encountered the same problem.

From the home diretory, I `cd` into the `Documents` directory and then used both `dir` and `dir /a` but the only items that showed up were:

```
<DIR>        .
<DIR>        ..
         402 desktop.ini
```

Yet, when I check the same Documents directory through the user interface, there are clearly quite a few folders and files. What could be causing this problem and are there any strategies that I should try to be able to access the files in this directory through PowerShell or Ipython Notebook?

Comment: `dir ([Environment]::GetFolderPath('Personal'))`

Comment: `when I check the same Documents directory through the user interface, there are clearly quite a few folders and files. What could be causing this problem` - that you think it's the same directory when it clearly isn't? Are you looking in `c:\users\public\documents` by any chance, or the Explorer merged library style view?

Comment: Did you try to `cd` to `Documents` via `cd ~/Documents`?

Comment: This question clearly belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Documents` directory was nested in `~\OneDrive\Documents` while all of the typical `~\` directories such as `Desktop`, `Pictures`, `Music` were in their expected addresses.

Thanks for all the responses and help!